# How can a Vue component behaves differently in different states?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm new to Vue framework. Currently I am working on a little project that can create and edit a directed graph online. I wish some components can have different action for a event in different state.

For a requirement about a graph's node as example, if the application is in the edit state, you can **select** that node by **clicking** it, but if it is in the delete state, **clicking** it will **make it disappear**. Besides, there are a handful of buttons that are responsible to switch the current state.

Here is my question: how can I solve this kind of problem in a declarative, vue-styled and concise way?

P.S My project use D3.js as well, if your example are integrated with this visualization framework, it will be better.

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: your description sounds pretty straight forward.. save your 'edit/delete' state in your components data or vuex depending on the scope, and implement your click handler behavior according to your state..

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution:
have a property in your data called editMode, and check it in your click handler:
i.e:

`<button @click="editMode?selectNode:deleteNode">Click Me</button>`

where selectNode & deleteNode are methods in your component..

Comment: But this method looks hard-coded in the template. If the judgement is complicated, or there are more than 3 states of a node. The inlined code will inflate.

Comment: Of course you can just call a method on click and in that method check state of the editMode and call appropriate methods accordingly, this was just an example..

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I solved the same requirement ago.

You could pass a parameter to your event function, and it decides how a behavior your event function has.

```
<button @click=“todo(type)”>MyBtn</button>
```

Or

```
<button @click=“todo(‘edit’)”>edit</button>
<button @click=“todo(‘delete’)”>delete</button>
```

And the todo function like this:

```
todo(type){
  if(type == “edit”){
    // do something 
    // also you can link to another function to make your codes clear like this :
    // this.editFunction();
  }
  if(type == “delete”){
    // do something 
  }
}
```